# Vote limit approaching notifications for comments, questions and answers

Tags: discussion, bug, voting, notifications

I just went ahead and voted on some questions, answers and comments on UX. Upon voting on an answer, notification said exactly this: `You have 5 votes left today`. And when I voted 5 more times on questions/answers, I had some votes for comments left, apparently, which I then used up too.

Technically, I still had votes after the `Daily vote limit reached. Vote again in 22 hours` message appeared. Those votes were comment votes. It wasn't clear enough. I was in doubt, so I decided to upvote another comment and succeeded. After a few more times, "vote limit reached" appeared again, now in regard to comment votes, but with no such explicit mention.

So do I have votes left or do I not?

Comment: Honestly though, who cares? If you've reached your vote limit on anything, you've done your job; now, the purpose of the vote limit in the first place is to encourage you to do something else. Go outside and smell some flowers or watch a sunset...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, it would make more sense if it said the type of vote in the message though.  It would be less confusing anyway.

Comment: Meh, I think if you clicked on a comment up vote icon, and you got that message, it shouldn't be all that confusing that it's about comment votes. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Comment votes and post votes are two separate things.

You can use up all of your comment votes and still have post votes left. Same vice-versa.

In your case, you hit the *post* vote limit, but you still had *comment* votes left over. Then you upvoted comments, and had no comment votes left.